# How to count the number of times a string is in an Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

So I have an Excel sheet and it contains a column that has product labels in it and I need to count how often every label is in the column

It looks like this:

> Apples
>   Bananas
>   Apples
>   Apples

And I need to count how often Apples and Bananas are in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CountIf function to do this easily.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Specifically, for your example, to count the number of items that have "Apples", you need to paste this in a field.

> =COUNTIF(A3:A8,"Apples")

See this image for a similar example.

[image]